# how to type function combining other functions in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function similar to (but simpler than) redux's combineReducers, but I'm not quite sure how to type it. Here's the javascript

```js
function handler1({item})  { 
}

function handler2({item, otherItem})  { 
}

function combineHandlers(...handlers) { 
  return (items) => {
    handlers.forEach(handler => {
      handler(items);
    });
  }
}

const combined = combineHandlers(handler1, handler2);
combined({item: whatever, otherItem: whatever2})
```

the idea is that handler1, handler2, and combineHandlers are all going to get passed an object with items as the values. The handlers will care about certain items on that top-level object, which may or may not be the same as the items the other handlers care about. The combined version will just call all of the other handlers. Nothing fancy.

I have a helper to generate the type of the function that should be returned by combineHandlers. I want to make sure that it's type safe so that given the right parameters to that helper, it would require the correct handlers passed to combineHandlers to match the type. Basically I want the following to be type safe.

```js
type SharedType = {
  shared: number;
}

type Foo = SharedType & {
   stuff: number
}

type ObjWithFoo = {
    foo: Foo
};

type Bar = SharedType & {
   otherStuff: string
}
type ObjWithBar = {
    bar: Bar;
}

function handler1(objs: ObjWithFoo): void  { 
}

function handler2(objs: ObjWithFoo & ObjWithBar): void  { 
}

type CombinedFooAndBarHandler = CombinedHandler<ObjWithFoo, ObjWithBar>;
const foo: CombinedFooAndBarHandler = combineHandlers(handler1, handler2);
```

It seems like `CombinedFooAndBarHandler` has the proper type I am looking for. But combineHandlers has a type error. My goal is for the last line to type check as you'd expect it to (the types of the handlers need to match the generic params passed to CombinedHandler).

[Here's the full version of what I have so far.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4oAKAKCliggA8c4ATfKAK5wA1nCQB3OFAD8jYQC5YASjo0AbkgQ8oiuBDV4mKztz5zFCOADM8UDCtrrNPFjLuvd+vAG4mTAPT+AFYC+MBQALYAhsIQ-PhIEdCgkPwQUfgItsBIULjpPAB0UDxIcXAA5OFRJAJRADb1ICW5UXAgwAAWlgDmTCnQAKIcYG085Kg09KjsXBC8-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-hBUEdl0eAYsAcEITBRZ9N+bwYUE2FdNRKz0IxrBfDiihCb4KFWEIJBkFA2K8MCuDggwnbdoofECZ0eFKIoF7aJBUBfn4slwPJKCKUCeDkupXY9lA2k4bpgHgU5WEuUJ+nns4rAbKZqF3oCym2PQ9maZ6BbWnqz6xg4TiXn4gTRGAUDMSquC4FEzTHFA5mWVIAz8DkKpSDi2W5ScGVWAgBDhKM2VJGO6UEvgQXQAACjiUQRHKACCWU5eQACyHqDZV5B-nJk5wMe96EVsuz7IceUjecUAjVcHoMAwhT7TiPSOW0ICbKcCVlSAKiyN1TUQGO+CjVcVCbFW1yeE8JkyTNCl0u+vwhTwKmPTMJjUvwgMqWdVB7ftSlA3gjmbPthSoOdxmuPkbG4FIEWOfAZAjtgiMTmQ5C3b1A1DSAEwvXAb4frgpxUD5hlnqJ1mhQQhTEbggw1J0DDwyp7OLawwt4HjSi+NBtzS6434oW8nz-XoPB4f1vBCQqKs-GrkMgs5uGAeiRudEJVC+HScBhPlJEfN8vzq4Bms8Nr9B-XrEAGwQQs2ap6IS7g5LS0AA)

Comment: Is it acceptable to replace SharedType by a class SharedClass and replace Foo and Bar by classes that inherit from SharedClass?

Comment: I think so. Would that help?

Comment: Oh, I see you have wrapped these objects in ObjWithFoo and ObjWithBar. In that case, you need to have a shared base class for ObjWithFoo and ObjWithBar. The SharedType, Foo and Bar may remain as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a working code:

```js
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (
  U extends unknown ? (k: U) => void : never
) extends (k: infer I) => void
  ? I
  : never;

//just makes some types easier to read. doesn't actually do anything
type Expand<T> = T extends infer U ? { [K in keyof U]: U[K] } : never;


type CombinedHandler<
  a1 extends Record<string, SharedType> = never,
  a2 extends Record<string, SharedType> = never,
  a3 extends Record<string, SharedType> = never,
  a4 extends Record<string, SharedType> = never,
  a5 extends Record<string, SharedType> = never,
  a6 extends Record<string, SharedType> = never,
  a7 extends Record<string, SharedType> = never,
  a8 extends Record<string, SharedType> = never,
  a9 extends Record<string, SharedType> = never,
  a10 extends Record<string, SharedType> = never
  > = (
    objs: Expand<UnionToIntersection<a1 | a2 | a3 | a4 | a5 | a6 | a7 | a8 | a9 | a10>>
  ) => void;

type SharedType = {
  shared: number;
}

type Foo = SharedType & {
  stuff: number
}

type ObjWithFoo = {
  foo: Foo
};

type Bar = SharedType & {
  otherStuff: string
}

type ObjWithBar = {
  bar: Bar;
}

function handler1(objs: ObjWithFoo): void {
}

function handler2(objs: ObjWithFoo & ObjWithBar): void {
  objs.bar.otherStuff
}

/**
 * Treat it as a base type of any function
 * You  don't need to write types for every function
 * Let TS do the job
 */
type Fn = (...args: any[]) => any

type SafeParameters<T> = T extends Fn ? Parameters<T>[0] : never

function combineHandlers<T extends Fn, Rest extends T[]>(...handlers: [...Rest]) {
  return (objs: SafeParameters<UnionToIntersection<Rest[number]>>): void => {
    handlers.forEach(handler => {
      handler(objs);
    });
  }
}

type CombinedFooAndBar = CombinedHandler<ObjWithFoo, ObjWithBar>;
const fooAndBar = combineHandlers(handler1, handler2)((
  {
    foo: { shared: 1, stuff: 1 },
    bar: { shared: 1, otherStuff: 'sd' }
  }
)); // ok

const foo = combineHandlers(handler1, handler2)((
  {
    foo: { shared: 1, stuff: 1 },
   // bar: { shared: 1, otherStuff: 'sd' }
  }
)); // expected error
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgSwPZwCpIJJ2BATgZwgGNhk4AeGAPigF4oAKAKCliggA8c4ATfKAK5wA1nCQB3OFAD8jYQC5YASjo0AbkgQ8oiuBDV4mKztz5zFCOADM8UDCtrrNPFjLuvd%20vAG4mTAPT%20AFYC%20MBQALYAhsIQ-PhIEdCgkPwQUfgItsBIULjpPAB0UDxIcXAA5OFRJAJRADb1ICW5UXAgwAAWlgDmTCnQAKIcYG085Kg09KjsXBC8-JY2uGyyAN5QANoA0lCWULEgSFawALqKMDunUAC%20OlB6Bri%20fgNQAMKJAEaWEDwAEmN6nhyK4ogBGWamfgAJWISFw4zCuF6ABooABlTpRfI8VDgCBTB5eXCosEAJih8zMcKICKRwBRcB66KxOL%20%20MgRMeeDJrCiAGYqQsoLT6eRkWjMdjcZzCXRiU8%20VAogAWYU0%20GIiWMqVs2UE7kk5VRACsGthWoZTJZ0vZeMNCp5pLBADYLaKrTqbayZRzHfRnSaAOwesXayXM332uVGpVggAcYa9kdt%20v9XKdxrBAE5k3SI7qo3aDZnA9n%20eCAAz58Wp6Ol%20Xlp6uInMVisJBfIL4RTDUa8SiIFDoLA4AjEUgocgQqAAHxVlIXgvnKvVy-Ny-dy9Dy6Ty7zy%20rVCorgcTi0Lze6YdkAVa1c%20D9PF0AgiXx8TBurwJUAAYkguT0DecpQAAZFAD6sGEAhWFYr7voY379L%20ADy3YAOoIF0AFAZBrhWIBii4V%20V6-gAQjiCogb%20EFQVASBdHgGLALB8FQKmX4-ne6FBFhXSUSs9D0V8OKKIJvjIVYQgkGQUDYrwwK4OCDBdj2ii8fxnS4UoigaFo%20FSTJU5SApPBKeSqndr2UCadh2mAeBtmYfZgm6VA%20naPRan4IUom4IUjGdMxrFwVxAQAFQRSwEVQKg%20RROE2EqvwURQKJhBQG8xwqu0UDSXAskoDFUAAJpIAIrClJU4R6H8WW5OIKI4FlBL8IRKwks0BVFXAJUADIQOEqAYi0WXBVAQRdjF-goXef5SPQDCFCtOI9DZbQgJspznrlIDcdAGJRDYAAKOJREk474BMRIzCY1L8AtbhnbgF1DXg12TJsVbXJ4LZMD1JlQHS76-ICikfRMHoLeicJhB6qDbVQy0rWZSk2ZsK2FHDwA7fhrD5KxuBSFZ6mYsdEAvW9V1DmQo7YB9k5kOQOObHAb4frgpwnu5nmqPjHZox9hQdYMNSdAwQtCTQ9EdvJQJ4KT%20BKL4cs3CrrjfshbyfKDeg8LhACCvCCQqus-Pr4PmSCdk4YB6K250glUL4dJwPDhFIMbPCm-QIMWxAVvo5LCvKeiUvkkoDDtgLrCe4oGxPvaijguiMFwSntzKqw-kJxxz4p%20iQUhWxigVPgPAVLcmtGCrUCBAxwh%20G7HuOX73xg6H%20AhxDYfy73kfR64sv5URkH58nUCpxxoXsZCNzZw3ufj0nuKFwxTG4CxpdQOXlfV6w35KHXDecJAJD1XguAIkAA)

This line:`<T extends Fn, Rest extends T[]>(...handlers: [...Rest]` allows TS to infer every passed function, so you don't need to worry about it

Comment: This resolves the compiler error, but it is not type safe. For example, if you add   `console.log(objs.bar.otherStuff)` inside function `handler2`, then you don't get a compiler error, but you do get a runtime error.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl fair enough. Made an update, whould be ok

Comment: Wow, impressive! I didn't know that this was possible in Typescript. One disadvantage: it is hard to understand/maintain for the average Typescript developer.

Comment: cool! I think this works! Thanks! I would edit it slightly to make clear that you can explicitly type `fooAndBar` as `CombinedFooAndBar` and it will work, but if you were to forget one of the generic params to `CombinedHandler` it would error

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues, I will try to help

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl, thanks. I agree, this all generic things are hard in TS.

Answer (score 1):

Function `handler1` does not accept arguments of type `ObjWithBar`. It might access `stuff`, which is not present in objects of type `ObjWithBar`. You combine `handler1` with `handler2` to get a function that handles both objects of type `ObjectWithFoo` and `ObjectWithBar`, but this is rejected by Typescript, because it is not type safe, because `handler1` may access `stuff`.

You can only combine handler functions that are guaranteed to access only `shared` and not `stuff` or `otherStuff`. In other words, the handler functions must have an argument of a type that guarantees this.

You have to create a type `ObjWithShared` and combine only handlers with an argument of type `ObjWithShared`, for example as follows:

```
abstract class ObjWithShared {
  abstract get sharedObj() : SharedType
}

class ObjWithFoo extends ObjWithShared {

  foo: Foo

  constructor(foo: Foo) { 
    super()
    this.foo = foo
  }

  get sharedObj(): SharedType {
    return this.foo
  }
}

class ObjWithBar extends ObjWithShared {

  bar: Bar

  constructor(bar: Bar) {
    super()
    this.bar = bar
  }

  get sharedObj(): SharedType {
    return this.bar
  }
}

function handler1(objs: ObjWithShared): void  {
  console.log(`handler1 handles ${objs.constructor.name}, ${objs.sharedObj.shared}`) 
}

function handler2(objs: ObjWithShared): void  { 
  console.log(`handler2 handles ${objs.constructor.name}, ${objs.sharedObj.shared}`) 
}

type Handler = (objs: ObjWithShared) => void;

function combineHandlers(...handlers: Handler[]): Handler {
  return (objs: ObjWithShared) => {
    handlers.forEach(handler => handler(objs))
  }
}

const combinedFooAndBar: Handler = combineHandlers(handler1, handler2)
```

Here is some code to demonstrate the combined handler:

```
const foo: Foo = { shared: 111, stuff: 10}
const bar: Bar = { shared: 222, otherStuff: 'a'}
const objWithFoo = new ObjWithFoo(foo)
const objWithBar = new ObjWithBar(bar)

combinedFooAndBar(objWithFoo)
combinedFooAndBar(objWithBar)
```

The output is:

```
handler1 handles ObjWithFoo, 111
handler2 handles ObjWithFoo, 111
handler1 handles ObjWithBar, 222
handler2 handles ObjWithBar, 222
```

Comment: Hmmm I don't think this will give me the type safety I'm looking for. I want to make it so that i can explicitly type `combinedFooAndBar` and then if I forget a parameter to it that one of my handlers needs, it will have a type error.